# How to preg_replace text to strong tag in php

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I wanted to replace

```
&lt;strong&gt;abc&lt;/strong&gt;
```

to this

```
<strong>abc</strong>
```

**PHP**

```
preg_replace('/(&lt;strong&gt;(.*?)&lt;/strong&gt;)/', '<strong>\\2</strong>', $input)
```

Give an error

Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 't' in D:\xampp\htdocs\myquestion\p\method.php on line 94

I'm newbie about regex please help. Many thanks.

Comment: you can use html_entity_decode("&lt;strong&gt;abc&lt;/strong&gt"); to switch back to html - http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the front-slash in your pattern.

```
 preg_replace('/&lt;strong&gt;(.*)&lt;\/strong&gt;/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

JUst use htmlspecialchars_decode() function

Other way using str_replace

```
function replace($str){
    $badTags = array('&lt;strong&gt;', '&lt;/strong&gt;');
    $goodTags = array('<strong>', '</strong>');
    return str_replace($badTags, $goodTags, $str);
}
   echo replace('&lt;strong&gt;abc&lt;/strong&gt;');
```

Comment: I just want only this tag, for other i want to leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` for all tags or if you want only strong tag use this:

```
$what = array('&lt;strong&gt;','&lt;/strong&gt;');
$to = array('<strong>','</strong>');    
$str = str_replace($what,$to,$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
$str = html_entity_decode($str);
```